# Update all Highcharts chart series synchronously

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use the code below to display Highchart with 3 signals in it, that are updated periodically with animation. But the problem is that for 2 of the signals the dots are updated first and then the curve slides into the dots.
When I only have one signal it looks better, the dots never "jump" out of the curve. 
How do I update all the curves without the dots "jump" out of the graph?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
      
    <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    
           
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
      function initData()
      {
        var data = [];
        var time = Date.now();
        for (var i = -60; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({ x: time + i * 1000, y: 0 });
        }
        return data;
      }
    
      Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: { duration:500}, //false,
        events: {
          load: function () {
            var series = this.series;
            var len  = series.length;
            setInterval(function () {
              var t = Date.now();
              for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                series[j].addPoint([t, Math.random()], true, true);
              }  
            }, 1000);
          }
        }
        },
        title: {text: 'Live random data'},
        xAxis: {type: 'datetime', tickPixelInterval: 150 },
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Value' }, plotLines: [{value: 0, width: 1, color: '#808080'}] },
        legend: { enabled: false },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
            series:
            [
              { name: 'Random data', data: initData() },
              { name: 'Signal2', data: initData() },
              { name: 'Signal3', data: initData() }
            ]
        });
    });
    </script>
      
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint), it says the following on adding points:

> redraw    Boolean
>
> Whether to redraw the chart after the point is added. When adding more than one point, it is highly recommended that the redraw option be set to false, and instead Highcharts.Chart#redraw is explicitly called after the adding of points is finished. Otherwise, the chart will redraw after adding each point.

Changing so that `redraw` is done after all points are added, your problem seems to be solved.

```
load: function () {
  var series = this.series;
  var len  = series.length;
  setInterval(function () {
    var t = Date.now();
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      series[j].addPoint([t, Math.random()], false, true); //set redraw to false
    }
    chart.redraw(); //added a redraw here
  }, 1000);
}
```

**Working example**: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/q489nsgw/4/

**API on addPoint**: http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint